# Sending requests to perl socket

Tags: perl, sockets

I am trying to send and receive requests to the same socket in the following fashion.

1. open socket
2. send LOGINPDU,
3. recv response from server and if ok send TRANSPDU
4. recv response from server
5. send LOGOUTPDU.

Sample of what am trying to do below:

```
#1
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new( Proto=> "tcp", PeerAddr => "$IP",
               PeerPort => "$port") || 
           die "Could not connect to host => $IP:$port \n";
#2
print $sock $LOGINPDU."\n";

#3
while($ans=<$sock>) {
    $ans1.=$ans;
}
$sock->flush();
if($ans1) {
    print $sock $transPDU."\n";
    #4
    while($tns=<$sock>) {
        $tns.=$tns;
    }
}

#5
$sock->close();
```

The problem is that I am only receiving response for the first request.

Comment: So... what's wrong with your code?

Comment: What does this mean: `The problem is that am one`

Comment: @TLP i meant to say "The problem is that am only...."

Comment: @fixon I assume that you meant to say `The problem is that I AM ONLY`. You see, "am" on its own is only a preposition. "I am wrong" or "I am yellow".

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the problem is that your script stays in the first `while` loop, which waits for the response lines after `LOGINPDU` is sent to the server (step 2 -> 3)). This is because `readline` (`< >`) is blocking and the server did not send an `EOF`, which is (with your) code the only option to get out of the loop, but as a side-effect it would also close the connection.

So, if the server's answer is (only) one line you can try something like this:

```
$ans1=<$sock>;
$sock->flush();
if($ans1) {
    ...
}
```

Hope that helped a bit.